# How do I extend clojure.contribs json writer to serialize other classes

Tags: json, clojure, clojure-contrib

I need to create JSON objects from clojure maps that store things like clojure vars.  The base implementation throws this kind of error when it sees them:

java.lang.Exception: Don't know how to write JSON of class clojure.lang.Var

Can anybody point me to sample code on how to extend the capabilities of the JSON writer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I figured out the answer.  There's another SO question that answers it partially: [How to map clojure code to and from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436216/how-to-map-clojure-code-to-and-from-json)

But here's the code that worked for me:

```
(defn- write-json-clojure-lang-var [x #^PrintWriter out]
(.print out (json-str (str x))))

(extend clojure.lang.Var clojure.contrib.json/Write-JSON
    {:write-json write-json-clojure-lang-var})
```

Note that all I wanted to do is just render a string version of which Var I'm referring to.  You could, of course, do many other things...

Comment: The clojure protocols have a lot of hidden power

Answer (score 0):

An update to the answer from zippy for those of us using the newer `clojure.data.json`. This is code that will work with the updated/new library:

```
(defn- write-json-clojure-lang-var [x #^PrintWriter out]
    (.print out (json-str (str x))))

(extend clojure.lang.Var clojure.data.json/JSONWriter
    {:-write write-json-clojure-lang-var})
```